# Remove all parent directories from a list of paths

Tags: text-processing

I have a bash command that lists the directories in HDFS beginning with `/random`.

It goes as follows:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /random | grep '^d' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

It generates the following output:

```
/random/custom
/random/custom/hive
/random/custom/hive/jars
/random/app
/random/app/nifi
/random/app/nifi/egispub
/random/app/nifi/empgis
/random/app/nifi/ods
/random/app/nifi/ptcsm
/random/app/nifi/tmds
/random/app/nifi/ucmdb
/random/app/oozie
/random/app/oozie/efdm
/random/app/oozie/efdm/ensco
/random/app/oozie/efdm/ensco/standardized_efdm_ensco_parser_5min
/random/app/oozie/efdm/ensco/standardized_efdm_ensco_parser_5min/lib
/random/app/oozie/efdm/mermec
/random/app/oozie/efdm/mermec/cleansed_efdm_mermec_5min
/random/app/oozie/efdm/mermec/standardized_efdm_mermec_5min
/random/app/oozie/gis
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk/standardized_gis_opk_parser_10min
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk/standardized_gis_opk_parser_10min/lib
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk/standardized_gis_opk_parser_10min/schemas
```

I would like to modify my command so that only the full directory path is listed, as follows:

```
/random/custom/hive/jars
/random/app/nifi/egispub
/random/app/nifi/empgis
/random/app/nifi/ods
/random/app/nifi/ptcsm
/random/app/nifi/tmds
/random/app/nifi/ucmdb
/random/app/oozie/efdm/ensco/standardized_efdm_ensco_parser_5min/lib
/random/app/oozie/efdm/mermec/cleansed_efdm_mermec_5min
/random/app/oozie/efdm/mermec/standardized_efdm_mermec_5min
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk/standardized_gis_opk_parser_10min/lib
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk/standardized_gis_opk_parser_10min/schemas
```

How would you do it?

Comment: _"I would like to modify my command so that only the full directory path is listed."_ What do you mean by this? Do you mean that only `/random/custom/hive/jars` should be output (assuming `jars` is a directory)? Do you mean that only the path to the `/random/custom` directory should be listed? The full directory path to *which* location?

Comment: Also, did you try anything? If so, what was it?

Comment: Hi, I updated my post to answer your question. I have not tried anything yet. I am looking into awk, sed and grep as options.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to printing non-directory files only? Try piping your result through

```
awk -F/ 'NF <= OLDNF {print LAST}; {OLDNF = NF; LAST = $0} END {print LAST}'
/random/custom/hive/jars
/random/app/nifi/egispub
/random/app/nifi/empgis
/random/app/nifi/ods
/random/app/nifi/ptcsm
/random/app/nifi/tmds
/random/app/nifi/ucmdb
/random/app/oozie/efdm/ensco/standardized_efdm_ensco_parser_5min/lib
/random/app/oozie/efdm/mermec/cleansed_efdm_mermec_5min
/random/app/oozie/efdm/mermec/standardized_efdm_mermec_5min
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk/standardized_gis_opk_parser_10min/lib
/random/app/oozie/gis/opk/standardized_gis_opk_parser_10min/schemas
```

It looks for "growing depth" of the path read, and prints if that shrank (going back in dir depth) or stays equal (file on same hierarchy level).

Comment: lines need to be feed to awk with sorted and this will fail if you had a lines like `/c/d`\n`/e/f/c`\n`/a/b`. since you are checking the number of fields